# R: sort words by the frequency in which they occur

Tags: r

This seems like a simple question but I can't figure it out, I am trying to sort the occurrence of words in a vector by their frequency.

For example I have tried

```
x = 'it was a warm and sunny day it was a great day'
x = unlist(strsplit(x,' '))
unlist(sapply(x,sort,decreasing=T))
```

However, this only seems to sort the words in the order they occur.
Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Perhaps `sort(table(x), decreasing=TRUE)` , where `x <- unlist(strsplit(..`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @akrun notes in a comment, you may want a table:

```
sort(table(x), decreasing=TRUE) 
## x
##     a   day    it   was   and great sunny  warm 
##     2     2     2     2     1     1     1     1
```

Or you may want to just have a vector of the values in the order of frequency:

```
names(sort(table(x), decreasing=TRUE))
## [1] "a"     "day"   "it"    "was"   "and"   "great" "sunny" "warm"
```

Or maybe you want the original vector sorted with each original element included, so something like:

```
rep(names(sort(table(x), decreasing=TRUE)), sort(table(x), decreasing=TRUE))
##  [1] "a"     "a"     "day"   "day"   "it"    "it"    "was"   "was"   "and"   "great" "sunny" "warm"
```

Comment: You can use data.frame(rev(sort(table(ss)))) to get a long vertical output format.